# pairwise hamming distance between numpy arrays considering non-zero values only

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, hamming-distance

I want to calculate the pairwise hamming distance of a 2D numpy array.

My arrays is

```
A
array([[-1,  0, -1,  0, -1,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0, -1,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0]], dtype=int8)
```

I want to calculate the hamming distance between the rows of A, but considering only non-zero values. If one of the entry is zero, we dont include it in calculation.

My output should be

```
B
array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: Can you define hamming distance? Perhaps show a loop of how you would implement this, to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Do your arrays only have zeros and ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your arrays only have zeros and ones, then you have the following property: `r1 * r2` will contain 0 in missing locations, -1 where elements differ, and +1 where they are the same. You therefore want to multiply all possible combinations together, and count the number of entries less than zero for each row.

You take the product with broadcasting:

```
B = np.count_nonzero(A[:, None, :] * A[None, :, :] < 0, axis=-1)
```

If you need to generalize for values that are not always -1 and +1, you can use a similar trick to explicitly check for equality. For two items `a`, `b`, the quantity `a * b * (a - b)` will be non-zero if and only if both quantities are non-zero and different:

```
A1 = A[:, None, :]
A2 = A[None, :, :]
B = np.count_nonzero(A1 * A2 * (A1 - A2), axis=-1)
```

If you want to write the condition out explicitly, you can do

```
np.count_nonzero((A1 != A2) & (A1 != 0) & (A2 != 0), axis=-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling there should be an easier way for this (in terms of speed it should be fine since everything is array based, readability is a little hard). But here is a working solution:

```
from itertools import permutations

b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[0]))
idx = np.array(list(permutations(range(a.shape[0]),2)))
b[tuple(idx.T)] = np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and(a[idx.T][0,:]-a[idx.T][1,:], np.logical_and(a[idx.T][0,:]!=0, a[idx.T][1,:]!=0)), axis=1)
```

You first create all possible combinations of rows using `itertools`' `permutations` as indices and then for each pair of rows, count nonzero values in logical and of *subtract of them* and *nonzero values of them*:

output:

```
[[0. 1. 2. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [2. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: There's a simpler way, which preserves dtype. The idiomatic way to get all combinations of a given axis is to duplicate it with a None index before and after.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I can see that I can replace the first argument of logical_and with `a[:, None, :] != a` but I am not sure how to do the same for ruling out the zeros. Please feel free to edit my post and I will learn more. Thank you.

Comment: I don't want to edit your work. See my answer for what I think is the simplest solution.